# WordPress-based authentication from other webapp

Tags: wordpress, cookies, hash, vaadin

## The task

I'd like to create a webapp, probably in Vaadin, and I'd like to use it inside a WordPress site's admin area. Most of the things are clear:

- I can create a WP plugin, which'll display my Vaadin app in an iframe inside the WP admin.
- the plugin'll be able to create the menu inside the WP admin.

**BUT**

I'm not totally sure, how could I authenticate my user. I'd like use the WordPress's auth system. If my user is logged into the WP site, and has admin rights there, I want to show them my site. Otherwise, I'd like to throw HTTP404, or whatever.

## What I've already done

I've checked the cookies, the WordPress creates. I've found 2 cookies are created, when I log into my site, called:

- `wordpress_HASH`
- `wordpress_logged_in_HASH`

where `HASH` is the md5 hash of the url of the site.

Theese cookies looks like this:

- `wordpress_HASH`:
  *admin%7C1422101199%7Ckd5Qp39eAQc4JNZTUBxlSjAMKeQqdCX00l6bnc64dxu%7C3f19a3dd6e12f7c342059a40c7ffe64b923dc9f46707d67d303b0a8333344818*
- `wordpress_logged_in_HASH`:
  *admin%7C1422101199%7Ckd5Qp39eAQc4JNZTUBxlSjAMKeQqdCX00l6bnc64dxu%7Cdf8a63d871c0830ef98732e7deb68b28b58a8618bc7c42e36a1e26a13494f1ae*

What I've found about this:

- the `7C%` is a delimiter, stands for `|`.
- The first part of this value is the user's name. It's called admin in the current case.
- the second part (`1422101199`) is an Unix timestamp, it's the cookie's experiation date.
- the third part (`kd5Qp39eAQc4JNZTUBxlSjAMKeQqdCX00l6bnc64dxu`) is a sessionId.

  - I'm not totally sure, how it is generated. Is it random?
  - I've found it's sha256 hash in the DB, under the wp_usermeta table. There's a row, with a foreign key to my user (in this case to the admin), with a meta_key `session_tokens`. It's value is a JSON-like string, and it contains some data about the user: his browser, experiation time, and the hash of all of the currently used sessionIds. What is this string? How can I parse this? It's not totally JSON.
- and there's a fourth part, which is different in the two cookies. I haven't got a faintest idea about what the heck is this.

## My idea

My idea, is to parse this cookie from my app, and compare it's data to the data in the DB. But I've got a lots of questions.

- Is it secure?
- Is there any better way?
- Why is there two cookies? What's the difference between them?

Thanks!

Comment: i would probably look into wordpress plugins to see if someone has already written a SSO app.  Seems like the kind of thing someone would have done already?

Comment: @djb: can I check over the SSO, that my user is already logged in, or not? I do not want a second authentication. I do not want any login screen in my app.

Comment: it is certainly possible, and very likely already written.  I'll look around for a bit

Comment: An alternative approach would be to create a PHP script on your WordPress server that receives an AJAX request containing a user identifier and responds to let you know if the user is logged in. You could then send this request via AJAX from your webapp. I found a [plugin by Lester Chan that will tell you which users are logged in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-useronline/), that might be one place to start.

Comment: I gotta leave now, sorry, I didn't find anything, but Brock's idea sounds good too.  The thing about your original idea, is that your cookie hash will identify a user, but anyone who reads that cookie can pretend to be that user.  A hash that works for your vaadin app and your wordpress app would require a shared secret, such as a salt, to make it secure.

Comment: here's the WP info on cookies: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies

Comment: I just thought of an issue you're likely to encounter with the cookie approach... from my understanding, you can only read the cookie if you're on the same domain, so your webapp would not be able to read WordPress' cookie. However, you could create a custom login function in WordPress that creates an **additional** cookie for your webapp's domain

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll start with @BrockAmhurst's idea. The Vaadin site, and the WP'll be on the same domain, so it won't be a problem. But I'm not totally sure about it's security, and other stuff.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if its going to be on the same domain, why do you need it in an iframe? And is this going to be a webapp and plugin that is going to be used by other people on their WordPress sites, or just on yours? In any case, if the webapp and plugin are going to be hosted on the same domain, it seems to me that you could avoid the iframe and login issue altogether as you would have access to all of WordPress's functions like "get_currentuserinfo()" and the WP_User object. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @BrockAmhurst: the plugin'll only set the iframe. The main content of the plugin'll be written in Java&Vaadin. Can I access all the WP objects, and WP functions from Java? We'll amend a WP site, and add a lot of extra functions - all written in Java. But cannot change the WP site, 'cause the static content, the blog posts, easy content managing, and so on.

Comment: My response is too long for a comment, so I'm going to type it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are just reading the user name from the cookie, an evil user can guess or detect the username and fake that cookie and might gain an access to your Vaadin based part.

If you want a simple and secure solution, you might want to look into hosting your wordpress on JVM using Quercus. I'm doing that on one site and its working pretty well, faster than with basic LAMP stack (without php accelerator) actually. Then you can create a hook into your WP that [adds stuff to java session](http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#HttpServletRequestandHttpSession).

Another simple and secure method would be to access php session somehow from Java. I don't know how easy it is to read the basic PHP session data from JVM, but there seems to be some kind of alternative xml (WDDX) format for [php session serializing](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php). That should be easy to handle in Java - assuming you can read the session cookie from your servlet. The last options would be to store a random hash to another cooked and corresponding data (username at least) to some flatfile or into the WP database (which you probably are going to be using anyways).

Comment: Thanks, looks useful. The WP cookie contains an username, a cookie-experiation time, and a session id (or kinda something. A 43 char long, random string). The experiation time, and the hash of the sessiod id are stored in the DB also. Would it be secure, if I read the cookie, and verify the data from the DB? (The experiation time, and the session id with it's hash)

Comment: If you can verify the session ID is valid from Java/Vaadin app (via DB), it should be enough. Attacker cannot practically guess the sessionId. Naturally, if you need a really good security, you should also have https connection to avoid man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 0):

**SCENARIO 1**

This is the most obvious, and most secure approach that I can come up with based on what I know about your requirements. In the PHP of your WordPress plugin:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    $iframe = "<iframe src='YourJavaApplet.html'></iframe>";
    echo $iframe;
} else {
    echo "Sorry, you're not authorized to view my applet";
}
```

**SCENARIO 2**

This scenario assumes you somehow **need** to pass the information to your Java applet and you can't use the approach in scenario 1 (I can't imagine why).
Assuming you just want to ensure that "someone" is logged in, and you don't really care who, as long as they have admin privileges, then in PHP you would do something like:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    $is_admin = 1;
} else {
    $is_admin = 0;
}
```

Now, assuming you're building and outputting your iframe in PHP and therefore have the ability to modify the contents **within** the iframe, you'd do something like this:

```
<iframe>
<APPLET code="YourApplet.jar" width="300" height="50">
<PARAM name="admin" value="<?php echo $is_admin ?>">
</APPLET>
</iframe>
```

Now you'll be able to access the value of the parameter "admin" in your Java applet.

**SCENARIO 2.5**

If you also need identifying information about the user, such as the e-mail address, then you could add this to that first bit of code:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$email = $current_user->user_email;
```

And then add this to the second bit of code:

```
<PARAM name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
```

And now you can access the user's email address.

It is important to note that there are potentially **serious security implications** if you decide to go this route, but being that you're dealing with a client-side applet your options are quite limited in terms of securing it.

Comment: Nope. It won't be a Java applet. It'll be another HTML-CSS-Jquery site, written in Java, with the framework Vaadin. It'll be a website for 100%, but, because it won't be in PHP, cannot use WordPress's functions, to check the user. The Scenario1 isn't secure, cause if I enter the URL into my browser, i'll see the website. The others talks about totally different task.

Comment: Nagy, I think we are misunderstand each other. You say you are creating a WordPress plugin that displays your app in WP Admin in an iframe.... So this means that via your WP plugin you have access to WP and PHP functions. You don't need to be able to access PHP from your Java app in order to take advantage of some of the PHP functionality

Comment: Based on what you said you can show/hide your app's iframe based on user status using solely PHP. If you are talking about restricting access to your app when using a direct http link (not in iframe) then this is completely different. In this case I suggest creating an additional cookie upon WP login that can be read by your site. You can do this by creating a custom WP authenticate or sign on function. But you said the iframe site is hosted on the same domain so this is what doesn't make sense to me

Comment: If I'm still misunderstanding, please post a clearer, step by step example of how your app and plugin are intended to work and I'm certain that we can figure out a solution